# Is $\Bbb Z^n$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z ...$, $n$ times?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, free-product

Let $\mathbb{Z}^n$ be the group formed by the external direct product of $\mathbb{Z}$ taken $n$ times, and let $A_n$ be the group formed by taking the free product of $\mathbb{Z}$ $n$ times.

Then, is $\mathbb{Z}^n \cong A_n $? I was told in class that both of these groups have the same presentation i.e. generated by a set of $n$ elements, with only the trivial relation i.e. both of them are isomorphic to $F_n$, where $F_n$ is the free group with rank n. However, I'm confused as to how they can be isomorphic, as $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is abelian and $A_n$ is not.

**Edit**: If they are not isomorphic, then what is the presentation for each of these groups?

Comment: Yes, your intuition is right, they are non-isomorphic unless $n=1$. You might have misunderstood what you were told in the class.

Comment: Presentations of abelian groups and presentations of groups are not the same. Both groups have presentations that we usually write the same way syntactically, but presentations of abelian groups come from specifying relations on a free abelian group and presentations of groups come from specifying relations on a free group. That these are different is what you're observing.

Comment: @Thorgott I see, so the difference is that the set of generators is assumed to be commutative in one, and not in the other?

Comment: For example, a presentation of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ as a group would be $\langle e_1, e_2, e_3 \mid e_1 e_2 = e_2 e_1, e_1 e_3 = e_3 e_1, e_2 e_3 = e_3 e_2 \rangle$ whereas a presentation as an abelian group would be $\langle e_1, e_2, e_3 \rangle$ with no relations.

Comment: Sometimes abelian group presentations are written without all of the commuting relations, in which case someone might perversely say that the *abelian* presentation of $\mathbb Z^n$ is the same as the *(not necessarily abelian)* presentation of $A_n$. If this came up in a class I would be very careful to wave lots of red flags to warn students not to be waylaid by this stupid coincidence.

Comment: $F_n$ is free in the variety of all groups, $A_n$ is free in the variety of Abelian groups. They both have presentations $\langle X\mid \emptyset\rangle$ in their respected varieties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}^n$ is typically defined as the direct sum of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. Also known as the free **abelian** group.

On the other hand, the free product of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, which you denote by $A_n$, is isomorphic to the free group $F_n$ (note: without "abelian") on $n$ generators.

These groups are isomorphic only for $n=1$. When $n>1$ then $F_n$ is not abelian while $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is. Formally presentations are as follows:

$$F_n=\big\langle \{g_1,\ldots, g_n\}\ \big|\ \emptyset \big\rangle$$
$$\mathbb{Z}^n=\big\langle \{g_1,\ldots, g_n\}\ \big|\ \{g_ig_kg_i^{-1}g_k^{-1}\}_{i,k=1}^n\big\rangle$$

Or a bit less formally:

$$F_n=\big\langle g_1,\ldots, g_n\big\rangle$$
$$\mathbb{Z}^n=\big\langle g_1,\ldots, g_n\ \big|\ g_ig_k=g_kg_i\text{ for any }i,k\big\rangle$$

So as you can see they don't have the same presentation: $\mathbb{Z}^n$ has additional "commutativity" relations. Besides they can't have the same presentation, because the same presentation implies isomorphism. Unless someone approaches the topic in a non-standard way (e.g. ignoring commutativity relations), but then he/she should be explicit about it. It is very unlikely for a typical mathematician to think that $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $F_n$ have the same presentation.